# Merging column with reduce, getting key error

Tags: python, pandas, merge, reduce

I have two csv files. I was trying to merge them. 
The fist csv file 'Test_base1' looks like:

```
OBJECTID,STATEFP,COUNTYFP,TRACTCE,GEOID 

1,12,105,10300,15000US121050103002 

2,12,103,24804,15000US121030248041

3,12,105,10800,15000US121050108001
```

The second csv file 'Test_file23_1' looks like:

```
GEOID,B23003e1,B23003m1,B23003e2,B23003m2,B23003e3

15000US121050103002,69,81,13,21,13

15000US121030248041,657,248,62,79,0

15000US120010004001,410,143,261,126,47
```

while I was merging them with reference to field 'GEOID', I am getting an error: KeyError: 'GEOID'.
But the  'GEOID' is present in the column name. Whats the solution? What is the problem with my code?

Update: It's not a coding error. Had a chat with @Zev. We figured it out that, it's not a coding problem. If I copy the data of files to a new black file, and create it, it worked. But I we do not know the cause behind it. Zev tried with the same file. No error on his side. But same error in my side. 
Files:
1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg706ck6bdda4sa/Test_Base1.csv?dl=0
2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yf49f2p7btkc56r/Test_File23_1.csv?dl=0

```
    import pandas as pd, numpy as np
    from functools import reduce

    df1=pd.read_csv("Test_Base1.csv")
    df2=pd.read_csv("Test_File23_1.csv")
    dfs = [ df1, df2]
    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['GEOID'],how='outer'), dfs)
    df_merged.to_csv('test1.csv', index=False)
```

the exact error:
[image]

Comment: Please post your exact error. Also, can you post the text (open the file in notepad or Text Editor) of just the first 3 lines of each file? I wasn't able to reproduce your error. The files (I just added a few of the relevant headings and one row of data) successfully combined for me.

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: @Zev added the screenshot of error  and pasted files.

Comment: Still works for me. I get a file like `OBJECTID,STATEFP,COUNTYFP,TRACTCE,GEOID,B23003e1,B23003m1,B23003e2,B23003m2,B23003e3` followed by 
`1.0,12.0,105.0,10300.0,15000US121050103002,69.0,81.0,13.0,21.0,13.0` and so on.

Comment: Are you getting that error from this exact code?

Comment: the exact code: 
"import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/shtanim/Desktop/Popgen2.0/Hernando_county/ACS_data_Hernando/')

df1=pd.read_csv("Test_Base1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("Test_File23_1.csv")
dfs = [ df1, df2]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['GEOID'],how='outer'), dfs)
df_merged.to_csv('test1.csv', index=False)"

Comment: everything same, I just have the changing directory. All other part of script is same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173108/discussion-between-zev-and-tashaho).

Comment: looks like `df1.merge(df2,on='GEOID')` works fine. what is your desired output?